# Get url parameter and save variable or cookie

Tags: regex, wordpress, url, nginx, redirect

I have a new installation of wordpress that replaces an old site.
In the old site there was a dynamic referl for users
**mysite.com/123456** or **mysite.com/somename**

Now I have to be able to intercept everything that exists after / then **123456**  or **somename** to save it in a session variable or in a cookie, (I have full access to the server).

I did some test with this code:

```
location / {
add_header Set-Cookie "secret_code=$args;Domain=$site_name;Path=/;Max-Age=31536000;Secure;HTTPOnly" always;
try_files $ uri $ uri / /index.php?$args;
}
```

But I find myself as a value other parameters, very likely for calls that makes wordpress itself

Also with this:

```
location ~ ^/(.+)$ {
add_header Set-Cookie "secret_code=$1;Domain=$site_name;Path=/;Max-Age=31536000;Secure;HTTPOnly" always;
try_files $ uri $ uri / /index.php?$args;
}
```

But this does not work nginx because it does not run PHP, and it makes them download

Which is the best way to solve this problem

Thank you guys

Comment: For the moment I have **solved** by writing a plugin in wordpress that takes everything that exists after the / and saves it in a cookie.

Obviously check that part of the url is a **404**, so I pass the right paths for the calls that are used to wordpress to work.

But if it is resolved through nginx always better, maybe others need it too

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is all you wanted. But, here is the regex to match alphanumeric characters after '/'

Tested and works for both **mysite.com/123456** and **mysite.com/somename**

```
/(?<=mysite.com\/)\w+/
```